# Change product color dynamically in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

So, we sell t-shirts in 4 different styles and in 12 different colors. So, we end up uploading 52 image variations for a single product. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

I was thinking, if I could upload a mask of the Tshirt, and replace the color of the background with the user selection, it would make our lives so much easier. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that could totally work:

```css
.item {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
Hover to change color<br/>
<div class="item">
  <img class="mask" src="http://www.genericorp.net/~vostek/images/circlemask-1024x768.png"/>
</div>
```

Make sure your mask color corresponds to the page (area) background color.